# Redhat Cluster custome fence failed

Tags: linux, redhat, high-availability

I have created a empty shell script for fencing like following

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "success: myfence $2"
exit 0
```

I have add it in cluster.conf but when for testing i down Ethernet down i got following error.

```
Feb 10 07:58:36 node2 fenced[2006]: fenced 3.0.12.1 started
Feb 10 07:58:36 node2 fenced[2006]: failed to get dbus connection
Feb 10 08:06:52 node2 fenced[1982]: fenced 3.0.12.1 started
Feb 10 08:06:52 node2 fenced[1982]: failed to get dbus connection
Feb 10 08:11:38 node2 fenced[1928]: fenced 3.0.12.1 started
Feb 10 08:11:38 node2 fenced[1928]: failed to get dbus connection
Feb 10 08:20:07 node2 fenced[1928]: fencing node node1.example.com
Feb 10 08:20:07 node2 fenced[1928]: fence node1.example.com dev 0.0 agent none result: error no method
Feb 10 08:20:07 node2 fenced[1928]: fence node1.example.com failed
Feb 10 08:20:10 node2 fenced[1928]: fencing node node1.example.com
Feb 10 08:20:10 node2 fenced[1928]: fence node1.example.com dev 0.0 agent none result: error no method
Feb 10 08:20:10 node2 fenced[1928]: fence node1.example.com failed
Feb 10 08:20:13 node2 fenced[1928]: fencing node node1.example.com
Feb 10 08:20:13 node2 fenced[1928]: fence node1.example.com dev 0.0 agent none result: error no method
Feb 10 08:20:13 node2 fenced[1928]: fence node1.example.com failed
```

Its not working!!! my cluster hanging for fencing at this stage.. but when i run `fence_ack_manual` it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself. added following lines in cluster.conf and boom!!!

```
<clusternodes>
                <clusternode name="CentOS1" nodeid="1" votes="1">
                         <fence>
                                <method name="1">
                                        <device nodename="CentOS1" name="myfence"/>
                                </method>
                        </fence>
                </clusternode>

                <clusternode name="CentOS2" nodeid="2" votes="1">
                        <fence>
                                <method name="2">
                                        <device nodename="CentOS2" name="myfence"/>
                                </method>
                        </fence>
                </clusternode>
        </clusternodes>
```